# "command not found but can be installed with ..." prompt in Linux Mint?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, linux-mint, search, apt

I'm running Linux Mint on a VM. I've previously worked on Ubuntu 20.04 WSL and I liked the feature where if you didn't have a program installed but if that existed in the repository, you would be prompted to install it. Just as an example:

```
zathura

Command 'zathura' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install zathura
```

I dont get this prompt in Linux Mint. It simply says :

```
bash: zathura: command not found
```

Now i could just do an `apt search ...` but that's an additional step.
Is there some way I could get this in Mint? My guess is to make a separate script or to put something in my `.bashrc` but i cannot figure out what. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: https://askubuntu.com/questions/821637/how-to-show-apt-get-install-suggestions-in-command-line

> The package responsible for verbose and more helpful "command not
> found" messages is
> [`command-not-found`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/command-not-found/).
>
> Install it by running
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install command-not-found
> ```